# Centering Slideshow Images in UL

Tags: html, css, html-lists, slideshow

I'm having trouble centering the slideshow images on this page:

http://turfsolutions.mrtechnique.com/athletic-field-services/indoor-athletics/

The images are in an unordered list and "margin: 0" auto is not working. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Flex is an easy way of getting the job done! 
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp

```
#image-slideshow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```